# Is it possible to compile and execute Blazor or .NET code in browser with WASM?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, webassembly

I want to make something like jsfiddle.net but for .NET. I know Blazor performs AoT tree-shaking so normally you do not have all the neccessary .NET library for it but is it possible to compile or request somewhere for the full .NET WASM and then execute some Blazor and/or C# snippet without a server?

I think something like embedding Roslyn may make sense? I am sorry I cannot provide any additional code as I really need direction at where to start here and Google does not yield any meaningful result.

Comment: Something like how https://try.mudblazor.com/ works? Though if you disable the browser's internet some assets don't work, not sure if that preventing compilation though.

Comment: @gunr2171 Yes! I am making a wrapper for some Web Components and would like for user to try their own code like that! I am not sure if that one is online or offline because most other sites I have tried, they have some kind of ID so I think they compiled it on their server.

Comment: After a quick inspection with DevTools, MudBlazor doesn't _seem_ to serve any user-specific file (though they do a page reload so it's hard to know). So it's likely it's possible.

Comment: @gunr2171 yep, all of it is compiled in browser. The relevant file is [CompilationService.cs](https://github.com/MudBlazor/TryMudBlazor/blob/main/src/Try.Core/CompilationService.cs) . That editor itself is based on [BlazorSnippet](https://github.com/BlazorSnippet/BlazorSnippet) Do you want to write an answer?